# MediaElement Windows Phone 8.1 does not play links to resources

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mediaelement, windows-phone-8.1

MediaElement Windows Phone 8.1 does not play links to resources, for example http://kgot-fm.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/449/31707/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/kgot-fm, but plays links. mp3. Windows 8 running all references. What's the problem? and how to fix it? the same code.

```
//only works in windows 8.1
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement" 
                      Source="http://kgot-fm.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/449/31707/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/kgot-fm"
                      AutoPlay="True" Margin="199,320,114,252" Width="100" Height="100"/>
//works in windows 8, and in windows phone 8.1
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement" 
                      Source="http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/businessfm96.mp3"
                      AutoPlay="True" Margin="199,320,114,252" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: sorry, confused, now change my

Comment: Also are you targeting Windows Phone Silverlight or Runtime? (if Runtime then add tag [tag:windows-runtime])

Comment: runtime. which tag? and where to add?

Comment: The MediaElement object can play Windows Media Video (WMV), Windows Media Audio (WMA), and MP3 files only.

Comment: @vits Not only those - [the list of Supported audio and video formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/hh986969)

Comment: @LAdmiral, Have you tried using BackgroundAudioStreamer?

Comment: Hi, @LAdmiral  I'm getting the same issue. how to resolve this.? did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you subscribe to `MediaElement.MediaFailed`:

```
MediaElement.MediaFailed += MediaElement_MediaFailed;
```

then you will see that using the first link you get:

> MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D2EE0

which means (HRESULT) that:

> 0xC00D2EE0 NS_E_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL
>
> The specified protocol is not supported.

The list of [supported audio and video formats you will find here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/hh986969)

Answer (score 0):

from the c# set the string as uri

```
MediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://kgot-fm.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/449/31707/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/kgot-fm");
```